# Save value from last year in current table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

This is a more general question about database designing.
I am currently migrating an Excel/VBA program to SQL and got following situation where i need food for thought, as i am doing this the first time.

Current situation in excel:
[excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiYiK.png)

Part of the new MySQL table so far:

```
+--------------+-------------------+---------+----------+-------+---------------+
| licenseplate | mileage_last_year | january | february | march | first_quarter |
+--------------+-------------------+---------+----------+-------+---------------+
| BP 11-111    |              NULL |     100 |      100 |   100 |           300 |
| BP 11-222    |              NULL |     561 |     1111 |   707 |          2379 |
+--------------+-------------------+---------+----------+-------+---------------+
```

"first_quarter" and so on are generated columns, no problem so far.

**But what is the best practice to save the mileage from the current year for the next year?**

1. A new table for every year and query it from the frontend, depending of the users selection?
2. A new row for every licenseplate/car and year and only display the current year in the frontend?

Comment: Normalize your data into `(licenseplate, year, month, value)`. All values (including values for year start and quarter intemediate sums) must be obtained by query.

Comment: Do try to stop thinking of DBs as bigger versions of spreadsheets,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to decide what is the granularity of the data you are going to store: 
here, it is at year, month level milage. So, accordingly you can decide the table structures and granularities.

You need to normalize into different table.

- Year Table(Year)
- Month Table(MonthId,MonthName,QuarterName)
- LicensePlate Table(LicensePlateId,LicensePlateName)
- Mileage Table(LicensePlateId, Year, MonthId, Milage)

You can now derive, what was the mileage for a specific year and month for a license plate. You can aggregate values at Quarter level when needed.

**Note:** You can combine Year, Month information into single calendarMonthTable(CalendarId, Year, Month, MonthName, QuarterName) which is at granularity of month level also.

Comment: Do not "over-normalize".  In particular, do not normalize dates.

Comment: @RickJames, agree with you. that is the reason, I mentioned that he can have calendarMonth table containing month level information.

Answer (score 0):

A database is a persistent store of data.  Do not think of database as having the power of a spreadsheet when it comes to formatting; that is for the frontend.

"no problem so far" -- Wrong.

Do not put an array of things across columns.  Instead, have one row for each month.

It is usually best to do the formatting in the client, not SQL.  But it is possible to "pivot" to put the months across the output.

Totals and subtotals should be calculated, not stored.

"new table for every ..." -- Almost always a bad schema design.  *Many* questions on StackOverflow ask that questions; the answer is always the same: "no".

"new row for every licenseplate/car and year and only display the current year" -- this can be handled either in SQL (slightly complex) or in the front end.